# How to set an hour before USER/EMPLOYEE can timeout ? VB.NET MYSQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Problem / I Want to happen

1) If employee/user time in she have to wait 3 or 5 hours to time out

2) If she tried to time out less than 3 or 5 hours she will get a messagebox/label that he/she have already timed in

This is my codes

```
getQuery = "SELECT dtr.time_in, dtr.date FROM dtr, employee WHERE employee.employee_id ='" & empid.Text & _
       "'AND dtr.employee_id ='" & empid.Text & "' AND dtr.rfid ='" & txtRFID.Text & "' AND dtr.date ='" & Date.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "'"
 getCommand = New MySqlCommand(getQuery, MySQLConnection)
 getReader = getCommand.ExecuteReader

 If getReader.Read = True Then

     TimeIN = (getReader.Item("time_in").ToString)
     getDate = (getReader.Item("date"))

 End If

 getReader.Close()


 getQuery = "SELECT dtr.time_out, dtr.date FROM dtr, employee WHERE employee.employee_id ='" & empid.Text & "' AND dtr.employee_id ='" & _
     empid.Text & "' AND dtr.rfid ='" & txtRFID.Text & "' AND dtr.date ='" & Date.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "'"
 getCommand = New MySqlCommand(getQuery, MySQLConnection)
 getReader = getCommand.ExecuteReader

 If getReader.Read = True Then

     TimeOUT = (getReader.Item("time_out").ToString)
     getDate = (getReader.Item("date"))


 End If

 getReader.Close()

 If TimeIN = "" Then
     disableTimeOutColor()
     TimeIN = Nothing
     TimeOUT = Nothing
     getDate = Nothing
 ElseIf TimeIN <> "" And TimeOUT <> "" And getDate = Date.Today Then
     TimeOUT = Nothing
     TimeIN = Nothing
     getDate = Nothing
 ElseIf TimeIN <> "" Then
     disableTimeINColor()
     TimeIN = Nothing
     TimeOUT = Nothing
     getDate = Nothing
 ElseIf TimeOUT = "" Then
     disableTimeINColor()
     TimeOUT = Nothing
     TimeIN = Nothing
     getDate = Nothing
 ElseIf TimeOUT <> "" Then
     disableTimeOutColor()
     TimeOUT = Nothing
     TimeIN = Nothing
     getDate = Nothing
 ElseIf TimeIN = "" And TimeOUT = "" And getDate = "" Then

     disableTimeOutColor()
     TimeOUT = Nothing
     TimeIN = Nothing
     getDate = Nothing
 End If
```

Comment: Where does TimeIn come from?

Answer (score 0):

Turn on Option Strict in the project properties on the compile tab. This will catch many potential errors before you even run your code.

First, your query. You are only selecting from one table so there doesn't seem to be any reason to reference the employee table. It is very important to rewrite this code using parameters; otherwise you are vulnerable to SQL injection.

```
Using cn As New MySqlConnection("Your connection string")
            Dim getQuery As String = "SELECT dtr.time_out, dtr.date FROM dtr WHERE  dtr.employee_id = @Id AND dtr.rfid = @rfid  AND dtr.date = @date;"
            Using cmd As New MySqlCommand(getQuery, cn)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = empid.Text
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@rfid", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = txtRFID.Text
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Date.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
                cn.Open()
                Using dr As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                    If dr.Read Then
                        TimeOut = dr.Item("time_out").ToString
                        getDate = dr.Item("date")
                    End If
                End Using
            End Using
    End Using
```

I guessed at the data types. Check your database for the correct types. It seems you are storing data values as strings. Dates should really be stored as dates.

The Using statement ensures that your objects are properly closed and disposed even if there is an error.

I really can't go any further without knowing about TimeIn.

Comment: in my database time in = time and timeout = time and date = date
i declared them as strings in vb
i'm sorry im just new i don't know which is good or bad code